# Type of discontinuities in Dirichlet function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I notice three types of discontinuities "removable", "jump", "infinite" defined here [Classification of Discontinuities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities) involve limit. Then I am puzzled that what is the type of discontinuities in the Dirichlet function, in which all rational numbers are mapped to 1 and irrational numbers are mapped to 0? They seem not to fall in any of these three categories? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classification you link to defines an "infinite discontinuity" to mean the case where "one or both of the limits $L^{-}$ and $L^{+}$ does not exist or is infinite".

That's precisely what happens with the Dirichlet function everywhere.